# Oracle SQL MIN(LENGTH(text)) OVER PARTITION

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying query data from a table like

| BUKRS | KUNNR | SORTL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2536 | AB |
| 0002 | 2536 | ABCDE |
| 0003 | 2536 | ABC |
| 0004 | 2536 | Null |
| 0005 | 2536 | ' ' |
| 0001 | 4515 | GHU |
| 0002 | 4515 | GHUKL |
| 0003 | 4515 | GH |
| 0004 | 4515 | Null |
| 0005 | 4515 | ' ' |

I want to query to result liKe

| BUKRS | KUNNR | SORTL | SORTL_FINAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2536 | AB | AB |
| 0002 | 2536 | ABCDE | AB |
| 0003 | 2536 | ABC | AB |
| 0004 | 2536 | Null | AB |
| 0005 | 2536 | ' ' | AB |
| 0001 | 4515 | GHU | GH |
| 0002 | 4515 | GHUKL | GH |
| 0003 | 4515 | GH | GH |
| 0004 | 4515 | Null | GH |
| 0005 | 4515 | ' ' | GH |

Data in column SORTL contain Null, ' ' (space). I want to get data in SORTL to SORTL_FINAL with the smallest length except Null and ' ' (space) over KUNNR.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KUNNR
                                   ORDER BY LENGTH(SORTL), SORTL) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT BUKRS, KUNNR, SORTL,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN SORTL END) OVER (PARTITION BY KUNNR) AS SORTL_FINAL
FROM cte
ORDER BY KUNNR, BUKRS;
```

The logic here is to assign a row number to each `KUNNR` group using the length of the `SORTL` value.  In cases where there be more than one `SORTL` with the same length, we sort alphebetically.  Then, we use conditional aggregstion over each `KUNNR` group to find the "shortest" value.

Comment: Thanks but i want to get SORTL with min length

Comment: @DungPham Sorry, I misread the question.  My update should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`first_value()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions057.htm):

```
select t.*,
       first_value(sortl) over (partition by kunnr
                                order by length(sortl) nulls last, sortl
                               ) as shortest_sortl
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant without using a CTE which I find easier to read as an SQL beginner. The code is derivated from the [answer of Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140004/16887829). Tested in Postgres but should work in Oracle as well:

```sql
SELECT BUKRS, KUNNR, SORTL,
          MIN(NULLIF(SORTL, ' ')) OVER (PARTITION BY KUNNR) AS SORTL_FINAL
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY KUNNR, BUKRS;
```

I used NULLIF to sort the ' ' strings to the end so MIN always finds the shortest string.